# SQLAlchemy dynamically filter on different columns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a drop down where a user can select different socio-econ statuses, however, the statues are separate boolean columns, how do I dynamically build a query based on selecting different columns?

For example if I have a model named `SamPublicData` and columns `woman_owned`, `veteran_owned` of type `boolean` (Postgres).

Say I have a dropdown select box with 'Woman Owned', 'Veteran Owned':
Right now in flask I have:

```
socio = request.form['socio']
if socio == 'Woman Owned':
    SamPublicData.query.filter(SamePublicData.woman_owned.is_(True))
elif socio == 'Veteran Owned':
    SamPublicData.query.filter(SamePublicData.veteran_owned.is_(True))
```

This doesn't seen very efficient, is there a way to dynamically select the filter column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I've done is to use the getattr built-in. You could try is something like this:

```
# map the string to the attribute name
def map_to_column_name(s):
    return '_'.join(s.lower().split(' '))

socio = request.form['socio']

SamPublicData.query.filter(getattr(SamePublicData, map_to_column_name(socio)).is_(True))
```

Comment: That could work, I am actually going to switch to wtf forms and the choices option is a tuple so I could just build the tuple like `choices=[('Woman Owned', woman_owned), ...]` and just map it like that?

Comment: @spitfiredd yeah you can map however (I would turn the list of tuples into a dictionary for mapping), but the meat of the solution is in the `getattr(Object, attribute)`.  However you get to a viable attribute name will work.

Comment: I was just able to do `.filter(getattr(SamePublicData, form.socio.data).is_(True))` directly w/o having to convert a list of tuples into a dict, this is using wtf forms.